# Continuous image load from web api in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have web api that returns last image taken from database so I wish to make timer to show latest image every few seconds using Flutter and Dart. Ideally I would like to load image, shot it to the user and request new image from server infinitely. My issue is that before new image is displayed, black screen appears so it makes flickering effect. How can I solve it? Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CameraWidgetState createState() => _CameraWidgetState();
}

class _CameraWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  late int a = 1;
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  late bool loaded = false;

  late Future futureRecords;
  Future getImage() async {
    final responses = await http.get(
        Uri.parse("https://0465-95-178-160-106.ngrok.io/profile/download?picNum=" +
            (a++).toString()),
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Access-Control_Allow_Origin": "*",
        });

    if (responses.statusCode == 200) {
      return responses.bodyBytes;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load image');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    futureRecords = getImage();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) async {
      try {
        //await getImage();
        setState(() {
          futureRecords = getImage();
        });
      } catch (Ex) {}
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: futureRecords,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData)
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );

          Uint8List bytes = snapshot.data as Uint8List;
          return Image.memory(
            bytes,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of trying various methods, I found out about gaplessPlayback property in Image.memory and when I set it to true, all magically worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

You wrap your `Testwidget` with `Material` or `Scaffold`,`Materialapp` widget.You can `AnimatedSwitcher` widget to avoid that flickering effect or default color

```
Material(
            child: AnimatedSwitcher(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              child: widget,
            ),
          );
```

**Before** (Flickering)

```
class MYAppWithFlicker extends StatelessWidget {
  const MYAppWithFlicker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TestWidget();
  }
}
```

[image]

**After** (Without Flickering)

```
class MYAppWithoutFlicker extends StatelessWidget {
  const MYAppWithoutFlicker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(child: TestWidget());
  }
}
```

[image]

**Sample Code**

```
    import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MYAppWithoutFlicker());
}

class MYAppWithoutFlicker extends StatelessWidget {
  const MYAppWithoutFlicker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.lightGreen,
      child: TestWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MYAppWithFlicker extends StatelessWidget {
  const MYAppWithFlicker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TestWidget();
  }
}

class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CameraWidgetState createState() => _CameraWidgetState();
}

class _CameraWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  late int a = 1;
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  late bool loaded = false;

  late Future futureRecords;

  Future getImage() async {
    var s = "https://0465-95-178-160-106.ngrok.io/profile/download?picNum=" +
        (a++).toString();
    final responses = await get(
        Uri.parse(a % 2 == 0
            ? "https://images.indianexpress.com/2019/09/toys.jpg"
            : "https://ecommerce.ccc2020.fr/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/electronic-gadgets.jpeg"),
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Access-Control_Allow_Origin": "*",
        });

    if (responses.statusCode == 200) {
      print(responses.bodyBytes);
      return responses.bodyBytes;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load image');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    futureRecords = getImage();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) async {
      try {
        //await getImage();
        setState(() {
          futureRecords = getImage();
        });
      } catch (Ex) {}
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var widget;
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: futureRecords,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
            widget =
                Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            Uint8List bytes = snapshot.data as Uint8List;
            widget = Image.memory(
              bytes,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            );
          }
          //      return AnimatedSwitcher(
          //   duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          //   child: widget,
          // );

          return Material(
            child: AnimatedSwitcher(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              child: widget,
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: It is still flickering, just with different color (white-ish).

Comment: did you wrap your widget with material of scaffold

Comment: I see it on your uploaded gif. Look more carefully and you will see that between two images, it hides image and shows scafold background. I wish to avoid that.

Comment: updated answer . you can use `animatedswitcher` widget

Comment: your solution is good for some image galleries, but I need to update it instantly because this app will act as camera surveillance app.

Comment: IF YOU GET A SOLUTION .PROVIDE AS ANSWER PLEASE.IT WILL HELP US